# How to add apps to Big Sur Finder toolbar?

Tags: finder, big-sur

Before Big Sur I can just hold down the command key and drag an app into the finder toolbar. But with Big Sur that has stopped to work.

I used to have vscode and BBEdit on my finder toolbar and after upgrading to Big Sur they just shows 2 big question mark icons.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Running **macOS Big Sur** (11.0.1) I can add an *application* to the **Toolbar** in **Finder** by first selecting the target *application* in **Finder** and then while dragging the target *application* to the **Toolbar**, and before actually being over it, press and hold the **⌘** *key* and then drop the target *application* on the **Toolbar**.

You will know you are doing it right because a green circle with **+** in the middle of it will appear when having moved over the **Toolbar** while pressing the **⌘** *key* while dragging the target *application* onto the **Toolbar** in **Finder**.

[image]

Comment: Oh right, only press the command key when the icon is on the toolbar not before!

Comment: @Qiulang, RE: "Oh right, only press the command key when icon is on the toolbar not before!" -- No that is the exact opposite of what I said! You have to press **⌘** _key_ **before** you are over the **Toolbar**.

Comment: No matter what I had added them to my toolbar :D